# Array of objects in a custom listview adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a custom listview adapter which contains ArrayList as a member.

Each game belongs to a round. 
I mean:

```
public class GameSummary
{
 String round;
 Game game;
}
```

So actually, I need to create sort of a section list view, which the round will be the header and the games below.

The problem is, that the listview engine generates row PER object in the array.

So if I will have 3 GameSummary and 10 Games in the array in it - It will generate only 3 rows!

What should I do ?

The current custom adapter inherites from BaseAdapter class.

Comment: With baseAdapter, the number of rows is controlled by the getCount method. But you look you'd be benefitting from an expandableListView instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use expandableListView and customAdapter like this.

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<GameSummary> mParent;

    public  ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GameSummary> parent){
            this.mParent = parent;
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }


        //counts the number of group/parent items so the list knows how many times calls getGroupView() method
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return mParent.size();
        }

        //counts the number of children items so the list knows how many times calls getChildView() method
        public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
            return mParent.getGameList(i).size();
        }

        //gets the title of each parent/group
        public Object getGroup(int i) {
            return mParent.getGameList(i).getTitle(); //game Title
        }

        //gets the name of each item
        public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
            return mParent.getGameList(i);
        }

        public long getGroupId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
            return i1;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }


        //in this method you must set the text to see the parent/group on the list
        public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_listview, viewGroup,false);
            }

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_parent);
            //"i" is the position of the parent/group in the list
            textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());


            //return the entire view
            return view;
        }


        //in this method you must set the text to see the children on the list
        public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_listview_child_item, viewGroup,false);
            }

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_child);
            //"i" is the position of the parent/group in the list and 
            //"i1" is the position of the child
            textView.setText(mParent.get(i).getGameList(i1));

            //return the entire view
            return view;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
            return true;
        }
```

and your class:

```
public class GameSummary
{
 String round;
 List<Game> gameList;
}
```